# 500.31 ANCM on Azure App Service exception message is missing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I'm getting this error message

[image]

I've tried to set env to Development and added UseDeveloperExceptionPage() middleware yet I'm not able to get a clearer image of what is causing this.When reviewing App Event Logs I see

[image]

so the exception message is empty. How can I further troubleshoot this Azure App Service? Deploying via github action. .Net version 6

UPD: I still don't know why the exception message is empty, must be MS bug but at least I found what the underlying cause was, described here
[Azure App Service deployment fails when referenced by Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72297391/azure-app-service-deployment-fails-when-referenced-by-azure-function)

Comment: Avoid mimicking the extra information as answer to your question. Edit your question& add these info . coming to your question , check with the Troubleshooting option in the App service. there you can get the more detailed error

Comment: The second screenshot is from the Application Event Log. What other troubleshooting option can I check that would have more information?